# How to get the bitwise symetric of a binary number?

Tags: c, gcc, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I explain my problem.

For example considering a 8 bit integer, to obtain symmetric number around "middle bits",  bits 0 and 7 are swapped, bits 1 and 6 are swapped, bit 2 and 5 are swapped and bits 3 and 4 are swapped. (ex. 10100110 => 01100101)

The sample principal applies whatever the integer length.

Following this answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/982139/7462275), I wrote this code that gives the expected result.

```
int bit_lg=8; // 8 bits (from 0 to 7)
unsigned int my_int=0b10100110, my_res=my_int;
unsigned short xbit;

for (int i=0; i<bit_lg/2;i++) {
    xbit = ((my_res >> i) ^ (my_res >> (bit_lg-1-i))) & 0b1;
    my_res = my_res ^ ((xbit << i) | (xbit << (bit_lg-1-i)));
}
printf("%B : %.8B\n",my_int,my_res);
```

I wonder if it possible to avoid the `for` loop. And obtained the result in one step ?
Perhaps does it exist some `__builtin_` (gcc is used) ?

Comment: https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#BitReverseObvious ?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: This is a common and useful operation. It or an analog is performed frequently during signal processing on devices that are ubiquitous around the world, and the ARM architecture has an instruction for it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Cool, good to know (the instruction is `RBIT` for 32-bit words in ARM if anyone is interested..). I guess I'll take my comment back

Comment: @MamilCuk. Thanks for this very good link. I consider this comment as an answer !!!

Comment: @EricPostpischil. Does it exist such an instruction on Intel Core i7 proc ?

Comment: @Stef1611: I do not believe so, although I stopped following the details of instruction sets when I retired a few years ago. Often, when a bit-reversal is needed in, say, an FFT, it is built into other aspects of the code, such as creating code that steps incrementally through a bit-reversed pair of indices rather than calculating the bit-reversal from scratch, or by using various table-driven algorithms. If you are looking for a practical solution, you should state what you need the bit-reversal for.